# Beyond Compare 4 - Not showing the proper aliment for differences

Tags: beyondcompare4

Hi All I am comparing two text files , using beyond compare V4 and it is showing differences as below snapshot.

[image]

Right file does not have CollectionCash and left file does not have CollectionsCO values. It should show blank/missing lines for values which are not present in either of files. I want to compare based on the first word fully matched in lines. I tried different rules but no luck. Please suggest how can i achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Beyond Compare's default Text Compare settings align based on partial matches. To only align exact matches:

1. Click the **Rules** toolbar button (referee icon).
2. Go to the **Alignment** tab.
3. Check **Never align differences** and click OK.